# Can an oozie instance run jobs on multiple hadoop clusters at the same time?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have an available developer Hadoop cluster to run test jobs as well as an available production cluster.  My question is, can I utilize oozie to kick off workflow jobs to multiple clusters on a single oozie instance?

What are the gotchas?  I'm assuming I can just reconfigure the job tracker, namenode, and fs location properties for my workflow depending on which cluster I want the job to run on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the clusters are all running the same distribution and version of hadoop, you should be able to.

As your note, you'll need to adjust the jobtracker and namenode values in your oozie actions

Comment: That seems reasonable.  I'll try this out within the next couple of days and see if it works.